# Expression Engine built in redirects?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, expressionengine

I just rebuilt one of our websites in Expression Engine and everything has been going great! I needed to create a bunch of redirects to hopefully fix some old URL's from the previous site.

Example:

The old site created URL's like: index.php?id=30

this one for instance needed to be redirected to: http://www.example.com/contact

So in my .htaccess I created:

Redirect /index.php?id=30 http://www.example.com/contact

I did this about 50 times for all the various ID's. However, when I go to these links, they just drop me on the homepage and keep the URL how it was. (www.example.com/index.php?id=30).

Then I noticed it doing this for ANY URL that doesn't exist. So I could type in:

www.example.com/asdasdjasdbjhasdbjhasdbjhasdbjhasdbjhasd

and it simply drops me on the homepage.

Here is what else I have in my .htaccess file with some examples of redirects. This first bit just removes the /index.php from the URL's.

RewriteEngine On

```
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

```
Redirect /index.php?id=30 http://www.example.com/contact

Redirect /index.php?id=26 http://example.com/careers

Redirect /index.php?id=28 http://example.com/about
```

So what is going on here, does Expression Engine have built in redirects that are breaking my redirects?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey there- you may want to check out the EE-specific StackExchange site: expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `Redirect` statement, you need to use a `RewriteCond` and match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. Make sure to add these rules **BEFORE** your expression engine rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=30
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ http://www.example.com/contact [L,R]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=26
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ http://www.example.com/careers [L,R]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=28
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ http://www.example.com/about [L,R]
```

etc.

Comment: Got it, thanks. This actually worked after my EE rules too. For anyone else, I needed to add a "?" after my redirect link to get the "id=28" crap out of the URL. Example: RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ http://www.example.com/about^ [L,R]

Comment: I would give you karma but I cannot till I have 15 :(